# Keil IDE Stopwatch not running

Tags: ide, remote-debugging, keil

In debug mode the stopwatch is not running after the 1st breakpoint. Continuing after 1st breakpoint, stopwatch t0 shows always same value.

Also odd: If we do a reset it's adding the time t0 from last debug session. until 1st breakpoint to t0. I have in mind, that the timer is set to 0 after reset.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

We had to enable Trace, then it worked for us.
Goto Target dialog -> Tab Debug ->Settings ->Tab Trace -> check "Trace Enable"